# Unconventional sorting of table elements using SQL in Qt

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

I'm creating a ticketing system and I want to populate a table for people to view all of the open tickets. I want them to be sorted by priority, from critical --> high --> medium --> low.

I'm reusing code from a test database program I made before, which ordered entries in a table by "last name."

```
while(currentRow < rows){
        qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY lastname LIMIT :f1, :f2");
        qry.bindValue(":f1", currentRow);
        qry.bindValue(":f2", currentRow+1);
        qry.exec();
        qry.next();
        currentCol = 0;
        //this loop will populate all columns in the current row
        while(currentCol < ui->table->columnCount()){
           QTableWidgetItem *setdes = new QTableWidgetItem;
           setdes->setText(qry.value(currentCol).toString());
           ui->table->setItem(count, currentCol-1, setdes);
           currentCol++;
        }
        currentRow++;

    }
```

Obviously I can't just change the query from `lastname` to `priority`, because they would be sorted alphabetically instead of the order that I want them to be sorted in. Is there a way I can execute an SQL query to sort them in the order I provided above, or am I going to have to populate the table and then sort it myself?

Comment: So, a `Priority` is present on the `users` table, and it is of type `varchar` (or similar)?

Comment: Well, I'm using a table called tickets instead of users, the code I pasted is just the one I'm trying to modify.  Every entry has a priorty but its type is "TEXT"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE WHEN ... THEN` construct to map your strings to numeric values to sort on, e.g.

```
... ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN priority='critical' THEN 1
    WHEN priority='high' THEN 2
    WHEN priority='medium' THEN 3
    WHEN priority='low' THEN 4
    ELSE 5
END
```